# Toggle onclick function on an image source in HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm pretty new to web dev so I'm currently working on a project to learn more JS.
I'm trying to add a toggle function on a speaker icon as I want it to change/toggle its src from its normal state to the muted state (change the image src).

I know how to make it change once but I cannot change it back to its original state.

The code looks something like this:

```html
<div class="tooltip" id="speakerbtn"><img src="images/images/speaker-icon.png" class="header-nav-button" id="myImage">
                <span class="tooltiptext">Sound</span>
              </div>
```

```js
 let image = document.getElementById('myImage');

    image.addEventListener('click', function(){
        changeImage();
    });

    function changeImage(){
        image.src = 'images/images/volume-mute-icons.png';  
    }
```

Comment: You should check what the current state is to decide on what image src should be

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do that with [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

If image `src` equal `isMuted` flag, then show the `muteIcon` else show the `voiceIcon`, on each toggle reverse the value of `isMuted`.

```js
const muteIcon = 'images/images/volume-mute-icons.png'
    const voiceIcon = 'set/icon/path/here'
    let isMuted = false
    
    function changeImage() {
       isMuted = !isMuted
       image.src = (isMuted ? muteIcon : voiceIcon);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working nice. Now give **`If`** condition to your function.

for example.

```
function changeImage(){
        if image.src === 'images/images/volume-mute-icons.png'
            image.src = 'images/images/speaker-icon.png'
        else 
            image.src = 'images/images/volume-mute-icons.png';  
    }
```

then it checks your image, if it is mute image it changes to speaker, if it is speaker image it changes to mute

**happy coding!**